# I want to read the data in the provided link in R

Tags: r, read.table

```
read.table("http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/datasets/regression/x06.txt",fill=TRUE,header=FALSE)
            V1      V2    V3       V4       V5
1            4 columns                        
2           44    rows                        
3        Index                                
4          Age      of  fish   (days)         
5  Temperature      of water (degrees Celsius)
6       Length      of  fish                  
7            1      14    25      620         
8            2      28    25     1315         
9            3      41    25     2120
```

I just want to know how can I read only the data part of this txt link in R? 
My read.table function showing Variables as V1 V2...V5 and Variables such as Index, Age of fish etc. in rows. Please have a look at the data by clicking on the link and let me know if it can be done.

Please tell me you know any other way to read this data easily.

Comment: Check the `skip` argument of `read.table`, that let you skip the first rows of a file. Consider that in the file there are also comments; if I got it correctly, you should set `skip=37` to read just the data.

Comment: nicola, is there anyway to skip a column? Here V5 is unwanted

Comment: Hi nicola, Thank you so much for your response. It also worked for me. Is there any way to read the variable names along with this command?

Answer (score 0):

You can read like this

```
df <- read.table("http://people.sc.fsu.edu/~jburkardt/datasets/regression/x06.txt",fill=TRUE,header=FALSE)[7:50,1:4]
row.names(df) <- NULL
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. Is there any way if I can see the name of variables instead of V1, V2, V3, V4?

Comment: you can rename them